# Uploading a file to a Webpage(IE11) with Excel Macro Vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, file-upload, ihtmldocument2

I'm trying to use the following code to upload a file to a webpage:

```
WD.document.getElementById("fileUpload").Value = "filepath"
```

'The code does not came with the property 'value' empty( = "") its just not 'there until i click the buttom "search" 
'and use the popup dialog to select a file. 
'Also when inserting the value by code, the source code
' returns 'value = ""' and whenever i try again,
' it still gets value = ""

```
WD.document.getElementById("fileUpload").Click
```

'The Click fires a windows popup dialog for selecting a file, so its not worthy 'to use it.

```
WD.document.getElementById("frmUpload").submit
```

'i can use this command to fire the event of uploading, but with a value = "" 'its going to return the "file not found" popup

'HERES THE SOURE CODE FOR THE SITUATION___________________:

```
<INPUT id=fileUpload size=48 type=file name=fileUpload>'the element

<FORM id=frmUpload encType=multipart/form-data method=post action=/ChamadoPC/Upload/12295979/1 target=fraUpload jQuery15105169442065138357="118">'the form
```

hope you can help me, hope everybody understand!

Comment: Is it possible to share the website so that we can see more code?

Comment: Its a private server, but i can post some more parts of the source code if necessary

Comment: There is an excellent multipart form file upload answer given by @santosh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51453795/6241235)

Comment: From your description, It looks like you are trying to load file for HTML input file control. It has property 'files' which returns a FileList object, representing the file or files selected with the file upload control. But this is a read only property. Due to this reason we cannot load the file value using VBA or JS for this control.