# How should I encode GIF file data in a multipart form using VBA MSXML2.XMLHTTP API?

Tags: vba, msxml, confluence-rest-api, msxml2

I'm trying to use ["Create Attachment"](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v1/api-group-content---attachments/#api-wiki-rest-api-content-id-child-attachment-post) API in to Confluence: it "works" but the resulting file in confluence is not being served as an image: it just appears as text, so I believe the processing of the file data is failing: assuming because it's not encoded correctly.

I've tried multiple combinations of encoding for the data (base64, raw, unicode) and tried adding utf-8 in API header... I'm sort of clutching at straws: encoding gives me a headache. Between a) XMLHTTP send encoding (utf8 i guess?) b) VBA String encoding (utf16) and c) ADODB.Stream (utf-16 i think) I've really got very poor grasp on how they all interact. My best guess below is converting the ADODB.Stream string to utf-8. Leaving it "as is" doesn't work either. I can run the API in Postman and it works fine: but I've got no idea how Postman does it or how to replicate: code snippet just says "(data)" where the image data goes. Tried using "postman-inspector" as suggested by some but I didn't really get anywhere (as it guess it packages the data in to some other form then the postman server does the actual send: who knows what it's sending).

For example: this tiny gif file: my requestData (for MSXML2.XMLHTTP.send) looks like this:

```
------IMabOUnDdfdfAaAAAA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file" ; filename="ttmRecordTypeImage19.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

GIF89a  "  !ù   ,      ‚ÿÿÿ™f ÌÌ™ÿÌÌÿÌ™         2XºÜþ/È)a8Ww3žÜ@i¡G6¡®jÀ  ”¿BmÏ(ãLpß®Ü¯ìÅ(¤’  ;
------IMabOUnDdfdfAaAAAA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="minorEdit"

true
------IMabOUnDdfdfAaAAAA--
```

I'm building that requestdata in to a string, with the "GIF Data Bit" coming from this function (have tried with or without strconv):

```vb
Function ReadFileEncoded(filePath As String) As String
    Dim fileStream As Object
    Set fileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    fileStream.Type = 1 ' Binary mode
    fileStream.Open
    fileStream.LoadFromFile filePath
    
    ReadFileEncoded = StrConv(fileStream.Read(), vbUnicode)
    
    fileStream.Close
    Set fileStream = Nothing
End Function
```

My API header looks like this:

```vb
    http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", GetAuth
    http.setRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck"
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;  boundary=" & BOUNDARY
```

If someone could suggest maybe a methodical way I could approach the problem: my "best result" includes the "GIF89" bit at the start so I assume that's a good sign? But looking in hex editor between original file and the one generated, it falls apart after character 15... I'm thinking I make a huge logic table of 30 combinations of encoding and decoding at various stages to various strings and objects but that might drive me insane.

I've read a few similar questions saying to use strconv(..vbFromUnicode) for the request data... Tried that with or without using strconv(...vbUnicode) on the file data first. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you view the "raw" successful post in Postman or your browser Dev Tools?  That should show you what you need.

Comment: I couldn't work out how to see it. Postman doesn't go directly to confluence by the looks of it, and the message it gives to it's own servers is chopped up (using postman inspector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I found the answer in the post below: encapsulating the entire thing in an ADODB stream, including reading the "string bits" in to a byte array. Not sure etiquette for sighting a different post as an answer?

Anyway this is the "magic":

```vb
    With obStream
        .Type = 1 'binary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile stFile
        .Position = 0
        vrImage = .Read
        .Close
            
        ' combine part, image , end
        .Open
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1 ' binary
        .Write ToBytes(stFirstBit)
        .Write vrImage
        .Write ToBytes(stSecondBit)
        .Position = 0
    End With
```

[Upload file to file.io using POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60890492/upload-file-to-file-io-using-post-method)