VBA sending a file to the server using the POST method
I'm sending a POST file with a request, but I don't understand how to encode it
Call CreateUUID(requestId)
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    
    ' Задать заголовки
    objHttp.Open "POST", fileUploadUrl, False
    objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
    objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
    objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken
    objHttp.SetRequestHeader "x-request-id", requestId
    
    Dim fileData() As Byte
    Open filePath For Binary Access Read As #1
        fileData = InputB(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
       
    strPayloadValue = "--" & boundary & vbCrLf & _
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & "ц-5 тест.xlsx" & """" & vbCrLf & _
            "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" & vbCrLf & _
            Binary & vbCrLf & _
            vbCrLf & _
            vbCrLf & _
            "--" & boundary & "--"
    
    objHttp.Send strPayloadValue
    
    Debug.Print strPayloadValue

status 500. The file is not an valid Package file. If the file is encrypted, please supply the password in the constructor
I tried encoding in base64, in binary system, and sending the entire file.
when I use this coding method
 FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Binary Access Read As FileNumber
        Binary = Input(LOF(FileNumber), FileNumber)
    Close FileNumber
      
    
    strPayloadValue = "--" & boundary & vbCrLf & _
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & Dir(filePath) & """" & vbCrLf & _
            "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" & vbCrLf & _
            Binary & vbCrLf & _
            vbCrLf & _
            vbCrLf & _
            "--" & boundary & "--"
    
    objHttp.Send strPayloadValue

I get an error Status: 400
Response: File is empty.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60890492/

In your first example you send Binary in place of fileData  and you've not declared or populated the variable boundary

@TimWilliams I declare a variable, I just didn’t indicate it in the code, the binary contains a “binary” file. I don’t know how well I’m coding it correctly.
```Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")


objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile filePath


byteData = objStream.Read


objStream.Close```

this is an example encoding

In that case please don't post partial code, or code which is not your actual code.  You can't ask us to help with code which is not identical to the code you're having a problem with...

@TimWilliams This is my code, it's just too big, it also contains sensitive information. if necessary, I can send you the entire code, excluding personal information

I managed to solve the problem using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60890492/
с
