# C# How to upload any file to a fileuploader?

Tags: c#, webclient, system.net

I need upload my file to "https://file.io" and i tried this:

```
   `private void buttonInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            var resStr = client.UploadFile("https://file.io", @"C:\data\test.txt");
            var jObjResult = JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resStr));
            var linkToFile = jObjResult["link"];
        }
    }`
```

It does upload target txt file to url.

But im taking that error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Hide Status
> Error CS01 'JObject' scope valid03

[image]

How to Fix it?

Btw im using them:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: What is inside resStr?

Comment: @DanFriedman i don't know i got source from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593284/c-sharp-upload-file-to-file-io-and-get-download-link

Comment: It looks like a compilation error. Did you add the newtonsoft nuget package? apparently not.

Comment: Hi I installed Newtonsoft.Json but nothing changes

Comment: Also i tried install JObject from nuget package manager but it gives me because JObject's version is 1.0.0 and im using .NET framework 4.7.2

Comment: i used using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; but im taking "System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned no error: (400) Bad Request.'" error